# Generate URLs for csv data in S3 as HTML table using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

looking for some suggestions as I'm stuck as to how i can achieve my next task.
i have a csv file `test.csv` in S3 bucket. Now, i have to read this file in my Lambda function and convert to HTML table and come up with a URL that i can save on S3 so that i can later
email to users. when users click the URL they should see this HTML table.
Read lot of articles but not sure where to start,
I'd appreciate if anyone break above tasks into steps then i can start writing code to achieve this step by step and can get help if i get any issue

below is where i'm in my Lambda function

```
let readParam = {
     Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
     Key: process.env.CSV_OUTPUT,
    };
    s3Param.getObject(readParam, function(err, data){
    const body = Buffer.from(data.Body).toString('utf8');

})
```

any help please... i'm trying to accomplish this in Nodejs

Comment: Breaking it down: obtain csv file contents from s3; parse csv to a html table, wrap the table in a proper html base (<html><head><body>...), write resulting contents to an s3 file, store url somewhere to use for emailing

p.s.: if you're looking to use an url either way, you could also just render the csv to a table directly (client-side); provided their browsers support javascript

Comment: after adding the code with `const s3Stream = s3Param.getObject(readParam).createReadStream(); fstCsv.fromStream(s3Stream).on('data', (data) => {
              console.log(data);`
            }) i get below out from S3 ["TEST","121","HIGH","WARNING"]["TEST","114","LOW","ERROR"]["TEST","165","MEDIUM","FATAL"] now how can i include html code in my lambda to populate this data into a html table?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@leafgard/csv2html looks like a good starting point ;)